# Test if an array is broadcastable to a shape?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

What is the best way to test whether an array can be broadcast to a given shape?

The "pythonic" approach of `try`ing doesn't work for my case, because the intent is to have lazy evaluation of the operation.

I'm asking how to implement `is_broadcastable` below:

```
>>> x = np.ones([2,2,2])
>>> y = np.ones([2,2])
>>> is_broadcastable(x,y)
True
>>> y = np.ones([2,3])
>>> is_broadcastable(x,y)
False
```

or better yet:

```
>>> is_broadcastable(x.shape, y.shape)
```

Comment: reference: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I really think you guys are over thinking this, why not just keep it simple?

```
def is_broadcastable(shp1, shp2):
    for a, b in zip(shp1[::-1], shp2[::-1]):
        if a == 1 or b == 1 or a == b:
            pass
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: I can't think of anything wrong with this... there aren't any subtle extra rules I might be missing, are there?

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to avoid materializing an array with a given shape, you can use as_strided:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

def is_broadcastable(shp1, shp2):
    x = np.array([1])
    a = as_strided(x, shape=shp1, strides=[0] * len(shp1))
    b = as_strided(x, shape=shp2, strides=[0] * len(shp2))
    try:
        c = np.broadcast_arrays(a, b)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

is_broadcastable((1000, 1000, 1000), (1000, 1, 1000))  # True
is_broadcastable((1000, 1000, 1000), (3,))  # False
```

This is memory efficient, since a and b are both backed by a single record

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`np.broadcast`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast.html).  For example:

```
In [47]: x = np.ones([2,2,2])

In [48]: y = np.ones([2,3])

In [49]: try:
   ....:     b = np.broadcast(x, y)
   ....:     print "Result has shape", b.shape
   ....: except ValueError:
   ....:     print "Not compatible for broadcasting"
   ....:     
Not compatible for broadcasting

In [50]: y = np.ones([2,2])

In [51]: try:
   ....:     b = np.broadcast(x, y)
   ....:     print "Result has shape", b.shape
   ....: except ValueError:
   ....:     print "Not compatible for broadcasting"
   ....:
Result has shape (2, 2, 2)
```

For your implementation of lazy evaluation, you might also find [`np.broadcast_arrays`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_arrays.html) useful.

Comment: `broadcast_arrays` is what I was looking for in order to get laziness, but I still need a verification stage - how can I test if shape A can be broadcast to shape B, assuming I don't have an array of shape B in hand?

Answer (score 3):

For the case of when you want to check any number of array-like objects (opposed to passing shapes), we can leverage `np.nditer` for [broadcasting array iteration](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html#broadcasting-array-iteration).

```
def is_broadcastable(*arrays):
    try:
        np.nditer(arrays)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Be aware that this only works for `np.ndarray` or classes that define `__array__` (which *will* be called).

Answer (score 2):

`numpy.broadcast_shapes` is now avaialble since numpy 1.20, therefore it can be implemented as easily as this:

```py
import numpy as np

def is_broadcastable(shp1, shp2):
    try:
        np.broadcast_shapes(shp1, shp2)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Under the hood, it is using zero-length list numpy arrays in order to call `broadcast_arrays`, by doing this:

```
np.empty(shp, dtype=[])
```

This way it avoids allocating memory. It is similar to the solution proposed by [@ChrisB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24765997/4820605) but does not relies on `as_strided` trick, which I find a bit confusing.

Answer (score 2):

When order is important, such as testing if `np.broadcast_to(a, b.shape)` will work, this seems to work well:

```py
def is_broadcastable(src, dst):
    try:
        return np.broadcast_shapes(src, dst) == dst
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

`np.broadcast_shaps`'s return value is independent of the order of the arguments given, we need to check that the result is the same as `dst`; that `dst` is the 'larger' size.

Answer (score 1):

To generalize this to arbitrarily many shapes, you can do so as follows:

```
def is_broadcast_compatible(*shapes):
    if len(shapes) < 2:
        return True
    else:
        for dim in zip(*[shape[::-1] for shape in shapes]):
            if len(set(dim).union({1})) <= 2:
                pass
            else:
                return False
        return True
```

The corresponding test case is as follows:

```
import unittest


class TestBroadcastCompatibility(unittest.TestCase):
    def check_true(self, *shapes):
        self.assertTrue(is_broadcast_compatible(*shapes), msg=shapes)

    def check_false(self, *shapes):
        self.assertFalse(is_broadcast_compatible(*shapes), msg=shapes)

    def test(self):
        self.check_true((1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3))
        self.check_true((3, 1, 3), (3, 3, 3))
        self.check_true((1,), (2,), (2,))

        self.check_false((1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 2))
        self.check_false((1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3, 4))
        self.check_false((1,), (2,), (3,))
```