# How to check two tensors have incompatible shapes?

Tags: numpy, pytorch, tensor

Is there a simple way to check if two tensors have incompatible shapes (i.e., one can not be broadcast to the shape of the other) before multiplying them? Errors such as

```
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (?) must match the size of tensor b (?) at non-singleton dimension ?
```

I could use `t1.size()[2] != t2.size()[2]` in what I do (i.e., I know when and how that happens, but there could be more complicated scenarios), but how do I say it idiomatically?

Comment: Should be the same as numpy? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743753/test-if-an-array-is-broadcastable-to-a-shape

Comment: You could set the tensor as a numpy array `x =  torch.rand((2,3,4))` and `x_numpy = x.numpy()` then use the broadcasting check @jhso suggested or manually look at the shape with a conditional statement ie: `np.shape(x_numpy)==?`. This will account for tensors that have the same size but different shapes ie: `x=np.random.rand(2,3,4);y=np.random.rand(3,2,4)` then `print(np.size(x)==np.size(y), np.shape(x)==np.shape(y))`